# Cant solve my syntax error

Tags: python, syntax

```
print 'Welcome to the Pig Latin Translator!'

raw_input("Enter a word:")
original = raw_input()
if len(original) > 0 and orginal.isalpha():
    print raw_input()
    else: #<---- this is returning a syntax error
    print "Not real Word try again please"
```

I am new to python and coding in general is have searched the tips on the code academy site and i cannot find any solutions to my problem

Comment: What *is* your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your indentation for the else is wrong:

```
if len(original) > 0 and orginal.isalpha():
    print raw_input()
else:
    print "Not real Word try again please"
```

you had an erroneous space in front of the `else`:

```
if len(original) > 0 and orginal.isalpha():
    print raw_input()
 else: #<---- this is returning a syntax error
^else should be starting here  
    print "Not real Word try again please"
```

In python indentation defines the block statements so it matters that they align correctly and consistently

Comment: i have fixed the indentation, on the question, is that how it is suppose to be ?

Comment: Your newly edited code is wrong, your intention is that the `else` should match the `if`, at the moment it'll generate an error because there is no matching `if`, it should be like my answer